# Json.NET IsoDateTimeConverter not working on Mono

Tags: c#, mono, json.net

`2014-07-21T21:47:13.032415435Z` deserializing this value into a DateTime field gives the following error:

> {System.FormatException: **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**
>   at System.DateTime.Parse (System.String s, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles styles) [0x00027] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.8.0/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:845 
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter.ReadJson (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter converter, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Object existingValue) [0x00000] in :0 
>   ...

Here's some code example:

```
namespace DemoClient
{
[DataContractAttribute]
public class DemoType
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Created")]
    public DateTime Created;

    public DemoType ()
    {
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var demoType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DemoType> (
               "{\"Created\":\"2014-08-25T01:20:23.60191161Z\"}", new[]{new IsoDateTimeConverter()});
    }
}
```

I'm on Mono 3.8.0 for Mac.

Comment: decimals are supported in the format.  Can you provide some code that shows the problem?  Hard to tell from "not recognized as a valid DateTime".  e.g. that would be true if your code didn't parse it as ISO 8601...

Comment: @PeterRitchie it's probably not decimals (I updated the question with code example above)

Answer (score 1):

I happen to be working on a project right now where I'm using JSON.Net. I put together a unit test using the string example you provided. It converted without error:

```
public void ProcessDataItemTest()
{
    string value = "{\"date\":\"2014-07-21T21:47:13.032415435Z\"}";

    try
    {
        var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTest>(value);
        var d = x.date;
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString()); //output: 7/21/2014 9:47:13 PM
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

internal class DateTest
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @jwatts1980 I added almost the same code above I'm using. I get the error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mono bug, not json.net

I got the same error trying to parse Docker api responses (same variable named Created, same decimal length in iso date string)

Everything was working on microsoft framework, not on mono, i believe because mono parse function could only parse iso date strings with up to 7 decimals.

Anyway, the bug has been fixed (see [this commit](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/db57c23c291653353bbd00996552cca02c95cd53)) and DateTime.Parse is now working on an up-to-date mono (3.10.1)